# Deleting bound item from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

I have a List of an object, set to DataSource of a BindingSource, set to DataSource of a DataGridView. Then I added a DataGridViewButtonColumn which I want a click to remove that record from the collection. So I simply call collection.RemoveAt(e.rowIndex) from the DataGridView CellClick event. However this produces an IndexOutOfRange Exception; "1 does not have a value"..

So is happening here?  I have maybe a vague idea, but would like to understand exactly which events are failing etc..  and what do i need to do to perform this action properly?

**EDIT:** 
This seems not to happen if I use a BindingList.. But when using a List, I get this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the error is because you're ultimately binding to a `List`.  `List` doesn't include the notifications of changes that your DataGridView needs to receive to reflect the changes you make.

If you really want to work around this you could do the following: just before you make a changes to your `List`, set the BindingSource's DataSource property to `Nothing`.  When you're done making changes reset your `List` to the DataSource.

This is a pretty ugly solution as you can imagine.  What you'll want to do this bind to an object that implements `IBindingList`, either a custom collection you create or a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28VS.90%29.aspx).

Here's a reasonable starting point for investigating this further:
[DataGridView Control Overview (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k39d6s23%28VS.90%29.aspx)